# Using local function parameter inside a while loop - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My inline table function basically prints out numbers, from 1 to the number that is input in the function. Since I'm new to SQL Server I am not sure how to implement a while loop inside a function. My implementation is below. As expected i get a lot compiler errors at `WHILE`, `BEGIN`, `THEN`. Can anyone suggest how can i improve the code. Thanks!

```
CREATE FUNCTION num_F(@nnn INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT CASE 
                WHEN @nnn = 0
                    THEN NULL
                    ELSE WHILE dbo.num_F(@nnn) > 0
                          BEGIN
                          THEN dbo.num_F(@nnn)
                          SET dbo.num_F(@nnn) = dbo.num_F(@nnn)-1
                         END
                         GO
                END as First_Col
        ORDER BY First_Col ASC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplest ways is by using a `common table expression (CTE)`

```
CREATE FUNCTION Numfunctn1 (@num INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN(
      WITH cte
           AS (SELECT 1 id
               UNION ALL
               SELECT id + 1
               FROM   cte
               WHERE  id < @num)
      SELECT *
       FROM   cte) 


SELECT *
FROM   Numfunctn1(10)
```

Comment: thanks but is this an inline table function ?. Can you help to form an inline table function

Comment: @user3760741 check now